# Passive Extraposition

Tags: middle-voice

It seems that for  verbs that allow the following sentence structure:

> a-type: "He [verb in past particle] that supplies were running low."

passive extraposition is possible, leading to:

> b-type:  "It was [verb in past particle] that supplies were running low."

The verb "think" could be used in both a-type and b-type sentences:

> 1a: "He thought that supplies were running low."
>   1b: "It was thought that supplies were running low."

Now, the verb "worry" could be, in the spirit of 1a, used like this:

> 2a: "He worried that supplies were running low."

But for some reason, "worry" doesn't seem to work in a type-b sentence (passive extraposition):

> 2b "It was worried that supplies were running low."

What do native speakers think?  Is there a way to pick out all the verbs that can be used in an a-type sentence but cannot be used in b-type sentences?

Comment: Non-native speakers could answer this question, too.

Comment: @snailplane  So, "It was worried that ...." is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

(First, let's get a technical grammatical issue out of the way. The verb form employed in your a-type sentences is not a past participle but a simple past. With most verbs the two forms are identical, but they have to be distinguished because with some (not all) irregular verbs they are different: *be* for instance has the simple past forms *was* and *were* and the past participle *been*.)

What is tripping you up here is the peculiar semantics of *worry*. In your 'base' sentence

> He worried that supplies were running low.

*worry* **looks** like a transitive verb with the *that* clause as its direct object, but this is not the case. This sentence employs a secondary sense of *worry* as an *middle-voice* verb combined with a *that* complement, borrowed from the transitive version of *worry*, which expresses the cause.

What is going on with the *that* complement may be illustrated with some similar transitive verbs which signify causing strong emotion:

> X frightens me *passivized as* I am frightened by X.
>   X angers me → I am angered by X.
>   X disgusts me → I am disgusted by X.
>   X delights me → I am delighted by X.
>   X worries me → I am worried by X.

But English does not like using *that* clauses as objects of prepositions.

> <sup>∗</sup> I am frightened by that he got the promotion.

Consequently, with all of these verbs the passive version takes a different form when *X* is a *that* clause. There are several solutions. *Anger*, for instance, prefers to recast *angered* as the frank adjective *angry*:

> That he got the promotion angers me → I am angry that he got the promotion.

The *that* clause may be recast as a gerund clause:

> That he got the promotion frightens me → I am frightened by his getting the promotion.

But gerund clauses can't be created from *that* clauses with a modal head verb, so most verbs also license the *that* clause with the preposition deleted:

> I am disgusted that he may get the promotion.
>   I am delighted that he may get the promotion.
>   **I am worried that he may get the promotion.**

An odd thing happens, however, with that last sentence. The ‘base’ modern sense of the verb *worry* is transitive: to ‘cause someone to feel anxiety’. Fairly recently, by linguistic standards, it developed secondary senses: a noun meaning ‘anxiety’, and an intransitive verb meaning ‘to feel anxiety’. The intransitive verb developed out of the transitive verb by way of a reflexive *worry oneself*, and it is in effect a ‘middle-voice’—the same sort of thing we see with the verb *cook*:

> ACTIVE VOICE: I am cooking eggs.
>   PASSIVE VOICE: The eggs are being cooked.
>   MIDDLE VOICE: The eggs are cooking.

Usually this middle-voice *worry* expresses its cause with a preposition phrase: I worry **about** his getting the promotion or occasionally **over** his getting the promotion. But since about 1960 there has been a growing tendency to borrow the active version's *that* complement:

> I worry **that** he may get the promotion.

That is what you have in your 2a. But note: this is **not** a transitive usage. *I worry* does not take a direct object, so it cannot be passivized. The passive-voice sense is already ‘built in’ to the middle-voice expression: *I **worry*** means, at least syntactically, the same thing as *I **am worried***, just as *the eggs are cooking* means the same thing as *the eggs are being cooked*.

And that is why you cannot say "it was worried*.

Comment: The verb "think" seems to be a middle-voice verb like "worry".  But it sounds very good, according to my limited English, in a passive extraposition sentence:  "It was ***thought*** that supplies were running low."  What is difference between "think" and "worry"?

Comment: @meatie Think is an ordinary transitive verb, not middle-voice: we think thoughts, but we do not say that thoughts think.

Answer (score 0):

> 1a: He thought that supplies were running low.
>   1b: It was thought that supplies were running low.

The meaning of these two are not the same, since 1b does not mention who thought it. You would have to say:

> 1b: It was thought **by him** that supplies were running low.

As for the second pair, off-hand I cannot think of a passive usage for the verb *worry*. But you would not say:

> It was worried that supplies were running low.

But you could use a similar phrase like:

> It **was worrisome to him** that supplies were running low.

although here we changed the verb to an adjective so the structure is not exactly the same.